# Posts that I flagged as "off-topic" should not appear in my review queue

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

I just recently crossed the 3k line on Stack Overflow, and given the huge size of the review queue I immediately started reviewing.

However, before having the necessary privileges to cast close votes I flagged questions for closure. One of these questions now popped up in my review queue, but when I clicked <kbd>Close</kbd> the dialog simply stated that I already cast a close flag on that post, and left no option to kind of convert my flag into an actual close vote.

I would suggest to remove those posts from the review queue - as I did not recognize the question immediately and spent another two or three minutes on reading the question and its comments again...

Comment: Or instead we should allow to vote to close a question which we have already flagged??

Comment: @hims056 I wrote the same in my answer at the same time you wrote your comment :D

Answer (score 1):

But why, they should appear in your queue! You wasn't able to cast votes back then. You can now. It is good that you are reminded to do so.

If you are treated as someone who actually did cast a close *vote* when all you did was to raise close *flag*, then it is a bug indeed - but the bug is in the fact you can't "upgrade" your flag to vote, not in the fact that you can see these questions in your queue.

Comment: I wrote in my question that I cannot cast a vote, and I cannot convert my flag to a close vote. That I cannot cast such a vote may be intentional, because that way I would be able to validate my own flag...

Comment: @Spontifixus And why would you be forbidden from validating your flag? If you would vote on question you have flagged, effect would be the same as if you only voted and never flagged in the first place - just like when you vote to close without flagging now. Why would it be bad? I understand what you wrote, I just disagree about what part of this situation is buggy.

Comment: Because flags usually get validated by other users than those who flagged the post. What I would second however is to be able to cast a close vote and validate the flag once a vote by another user has been cast...

Comment: @Spontifixus the flag's acceptance rate hardly matters. It's all about dealing with bad posts, not with making as huge number of "helpful" flags as possible. If flag helped you to remember to vote later, when you was able to, it was helpful. What's bad about it?