# Receiving review notifications for posts I've already taken action on

Tags: bug, review

Lately I noticed that I after I vote to close/reopen a question (or just place a flag on any kind of post) and my vote is the first, I see something like this:
[image]

(Excuse the fact that this may look a little funny, I wasn't able to take a screenshot so I had edit a plain screenshot instead).

Upon clicking the review queue button, I'll see this:

[image]

The queues are empty! This is because it is notifying me about a review that I have already completed, just not from the review page. Since I was the one to cast the vote, I can't review it; I already did by placing the close vote in the first place. I'm on a small site, so there's usually only one review at a time and the queue is usually empty.

As far as I can tell, this happens across devices and networks, so I'm just checking to see if this is an issue that anyone else is having.

*NOTE: I know that this question is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138240/the-new-review-is-showing-me-stuff-ive-already-reviewed), but that question is asking specifically about their numbers being reset and seeing questions they've already reviewed, this one is about taking action outside of the review queue and still having it show up.*

Comment: This is a duplicate and a known issue but it's not something we can easily fix. The indicator only checks two things - 1. There's at least n tasks in at least one queue you have access to 2. You haven't checked the review menu in the last hour. Comparing your available reviews with the count of total reviews and then activating the indicator only at that point... on every page load... is too much.

Comment: @Catija What's it a duplicate of? All the questions I could find that were similar didn't address the same issue, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to find it right now but it's been reported several times in a few different iterations.

Comment: Here is a very old identical complaint marked status-completed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142439/282094 and a similar one *answered*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202552/282094

Comment: See the last paragraph of the announcement of this change - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly Also, the [answer from Makyen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302608/284336).

Comment: @Catija that's pretty helpful, thanks.